# Why does timezone unaware datetime object print out in local timezone?

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, utc

When I instantiate a datetime object like this:

```
>>> print(datetime.datetime.now())
2023-09-16 10:30:15.50
```

I get the correct local time, which is currently around `10:30 AM`.

Why is it like this? Shouldn't it default to UTC time or something?

Comment: _"Shouldn't it default to UTC time or something?"_ - [_"Return the current **local** date and time"_](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.now), so... no?

Comment: To get your expected results the `datetime` would actually need to be timezone aware. But it is actually so unaware that it, simply said, does not even know it is incomplete.

Comment: @KlausD. Ah, I guess the confusion stems from mixing up "aware vs unaware" with "local and UTC" then. Forgot that it is possible to have "locally unaware" datetime objects.

Comment: what you're probably looking for is [aware vs. naive](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#aware-and-naive-objects). Be careful though, although the result of `dateitme.now` claims to be unaware of a time zone, it *behaves* like if there was one. Try converting to Unix time using its `timestamp` method and see what happens...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `datetime.datetime.now()` function returns the current local date and time by default. The local time is determined by the system's time zone settings.
- If you want to get the current time in UTC, you can use:

```py
import datetime
print(datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc))
```

Comment: Sorry, I got confused by the documentation "If optional argument tz is None or not specified, this is like today()". Thanks!

Comment: "*If you want to get the current time in UTC*" - what you *should* should use is `datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc)`. `utcnow` is an error-prone method (that should be deprecated imho) as the name suggests an aware result while in fact it is not. See also [Stop using utcnow and utcfromtimestamp](https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2019/11/utcnow.html).

Comment: ok, very well didn't know about that, thank you for sharing,  will edit  this.

Comment: I'm not sure actually when `utcnow` was introduced, but my guess is that it comes from a time when timezone handling wasn't really a thing in Python, as a work-around. That was definitely before I started learning Python with version 3.6. But I've seen it fail in action, so thanks for updating the post ;-)